# How do I fit header and img in div with set width and height with flex?

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I have an assignment where I need to fit an image and header into a div with a fixed width that changes heights every time. It needs to look like the screenshot below, but I have no idea how to get that look.

The sections are where the flexbox starts and I organized the child elements to appear like they should, but everything inside of that, I can't get to work.
HTML

```
<main class="card-grid">
      <section class="row-grid"></section>
      <section class="col-grid">                                  
         <div class="card" style="width: 200px; height: 280px;">  
             <img src="littlecolorado.jpg">                
             <h2>Another card</h2></div>                    
       </section>
    </main>
```

CSS

```
    .col-grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  gap: 20px;
  height: 2000px;
}
.col-grid div img {
  width: 200px;
}
.col-grid div h2 {
  display: block;
}
```

**My file:**

[image: my file]

**What it should look like:**

[image: what it should look like]

Comment: You will have to wait for this feature to be compatible: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Masonry_Layout or you can use any JS library for Masonry layouts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just setting the height of the image to `100%` should do it. That means the image will take up 100% of the available space. If you want more direct control of the growth and shrinking of the children use `flex-shrink` and `flex-grow`.

https://codepen.io/gallagher7788/pen/bGLRGLx
https://css-tricks.com/understanding-flex-grow-flex-shrink-and-flex-basis/

*Note:* `height:100%;width:100%` will distort your image, but thats how the example you included did it. You could create a div with a background image and use `background-size:cover` to crop the image.